# how to get OAuth2 bearer access token in b2c custom policy to send claims to My REST API during signin sign up custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have b2c local account sign in sign up flow using custom policies to sign in sign up
i want to add a call to my secure web API to send user claims to this API. i have followed this documentation [Secure your API and access through custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#prerequisites) and using OAuth2 bearer authentication. for this i have registered another application as the above documentation says, but i am not getting any bearer token in bearer token claim(access token).
i am getting this following specific error(in jwt.ms) when running my policy

error:**Claim "bearerToken" specified for the bearer token is not present in the available claims.**

**but when i add the Technical profile "REST-AcquireAccessToken" in user journey i can see it is returning the access token in bearerToken Claim.**
but when i add Technical Profile "REST-API-SignUp" in user journey i got the following error :

[image]

do i need to call both the REST technical profiles (**REST-AcquireAccessToken,REST-API-SignUp**) in user journey steps??
i tried doing so but it faild to upload the policy.
any help will be much appreciated.
these are the Technical Profiles i used first for acquiring the Access Token and second one to call API to send user claims

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-AcquireAccessToken">
      <DisplayName></DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
      </Metadata>
     
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="https://MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/api/.default" />
</InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
      </OutputClaims>
      
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

   <!--talking To API-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
      <DisplayName>Send account details to API</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <!-- Set the ServiceUrl with My REST API endpoint -->
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://My API endPoint URL</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
       
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
     
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims Needs to sent to My REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        </InputClaims>
       <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

In user Journey i am calling the Technical Profile "REST-API-SignUp" in step 8 like this:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTPostUserClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
```

do i need to call TechnicalProfile "REST-AcquireAccessToken" also in user journet step?if yes then when?

Comment: Have you missed opening <CryptographicKeys> in rest aquire access token ? I think you also  have missed closing </inputClaims> in both REST-AcquireAccessToken and REST-API-SignUp technical profiles.If missed , can you correct that and try .

Comment: If above was not the issue ,can you check Cryptographic keys used under [Error handling when authentication type is set to bearer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile.md#cryptographic-keys)

Comment: the missing elements were just here while adding the code here in POST but actually not. And why do i need to add Cryptographic keys as i am not using the Static bearer token. the only thing i was missing was calling the REST-AcquireAccessToken Tech Profile in User jpurney step. i needed to call both the REST Technical profiles, first one to get access token and  then 2nd one to send claims. when i did so, it resolved all the problem, now i am able to send claims to my secure API. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update @Munazza Osama , Posting the solution in the answer .

Solution:
The error:`Claim "bearerToken" specified for the bearer token is not present in the available claims`, got resolved by
Calling the "REST-AcquireAccessToken" Technical Profile to get access token along with  calling "REST-API-SignUp" technical profile in User journey.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
         <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange  Id="RESTGetAccessToken" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-AcquireAccessToken " />
               <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTPostUserClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
         </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
```